# Can I put "all" after nouns?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, postpositive

I came upon sentence:

> I am delighted that Lynch has found space for Wisden, Liddell and
>   Scott’s *Greek–English Lexicon*, and the *CRC Handbook of Chemistry
>   and Physics*, **estimable works all** (or at least the first two).

I am confused about the phrase "estimable works all". Is it right to put "all" after "estimable works"? What do we call this in grammatical terms if it is allowed? What is the part of speech of "all" here?

Looking forward to your answer!

Comment: It's a fancy way of saying "all of these are estimable works." It's grammatically correct.

Comment: "All" belongs to the part of speech 'determinative'. It would normally occur at the front of the phrase, but for some reason the writer has placed it at the end, though there's no change of meaning. The function of "all" here is adjunct. The meaning is one of entirety: the entire list of works are estimable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is right; it is also unusual. Here it’s probably a postpositive determiner, but under some analyses could be shown to be a pronoun used in restrictive apposition.

When we vary the normal word order in legal ways, this draws attention to the unusually placed word. That’s what I think is going on here.

One upon a time, the word *all* was traditionally classified as an adjective. However, in modern grammars the word *all* is more typically classified as a determiner in general terms and specifically as a quantifier, but it can also be used as pronoun.

The English noun phrase places “light” elements to the left of their head, and “heavy” elements to their right: *my many friends from college*. Determiners have a set slot towards the start of the noun phrase. The only arguable exception I can think of is when possessive determiners from the front of the NP like *my* are replaced with prepositional phrases whose objects are possessive pronouns at the back, so *many friends of mine from college*.

The pronoun sense of *all* can be seen in clauses like

1. All are good people.

So when we say:

2. My friends from college, good people one and all, have sent me cards for my birthday.

There we’re using *one and all* to mean *everyone* or even *every one of them*, as in:

3. My friends from college, every one of them good people, sent me cards for my birthday.

Compare these two orderings:

4. My friends from college, ***all* good people**, sent me cards for my birthday.
5. My friends from college, **good people *all***, sent me cards for my birthday.

The word *all* is doing the same job for both noun phrases in 4 and 5, but its unusual placement in the last one draws a bit of attention to it in the same way that the *of mine* in *friends of mine* is a valid alternate for *my friends*.

The answer to your question of *Can I...?* is yes, in certain very limited circumstances, but it should be used infrequently. It’s from a higher register, such as in more formal writing or speeches.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thorough answer! It helps me a lot.